# Updating email attribute in aws cognito through aws amplify is not working propertly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native

I have a react native project that has AWS cognito and AWS amplify integrated into it. Right now, I am trying to setup a feature where a user can update their email. Once the submit the new email, they will be shown a screen to confirm the new email with an emailed confirmation code. Once the confirmation code is set, the email show be verified in aws cognito and I will then update the email in AWS RDS database. For some reason, when the user types in the new email. A confirmation code is sent to the new email which is working. Then when I go into AWS cognito and AWS amplify, the new email is not set and the new email is not set to unconfirmed. Not sure how it is send a new confirmation email, but in aws cognito, the new email does not show up.

Here is my functions for updating the email and confirming the code:

```
const updateEmailForCode = () => {
    updateUserAttributes({
      userAttributes: {
        email: email
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setViewEmail(false)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  const confirmUpdateEmail = () => {
    confirmSignUp({
      username: user.username,
      confirmationCode: emailCode
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      setEditProfile(!editProfile)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error confirming sign up', error);
    });
  }
```

Here is what the existing email is:

`ricow81586@rohoza.com`

Here is the new temporary email I want to update:

`fimiw74710@seosnaps.com`

I submitted the new email and got the new verification email:

[image: picture of email verification]

I then get the following error:

```
 LOG  Error confirming sign up [NotAuthorizedException: User cannot be confirmed. Current status is CONFIRMED]
```

When I go into amazon cognito, it shows the old email and that it is confirmed rather than the new email:

[image: email confirmed]

I dont know why the new email is not showing up as the email and status of unconfirmed... Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening.

Here is my entire component:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import { Plus, RefreshCcw, X } from 'react-native-feather'
import InputFieldComponent from '../General/InputFieldComponent'
import { UserContext } from '../../Context/UserContext'
import MainButton from '../General/MainButton'
import { confirmSignIn, confirmSignUp, updateUserAttribute, updateUserAttributes } from 'aws-amplify/auth'


const EditEmailProfileComponent = (props) => {
  const { setEditProfile, editProfile } = props

  const {profile, user, getUserProfile} = useContext(UserContext)

  const [email, setEmail] = useState(profile.email)
  const [emailCode, setEmailCode] = useState('')

  const [viewEmail, setViewEmail] = useState(true)

  const updateEmail = (text: string) => {
    setEmail(text)
  }

  const updateCode = (text: string) => {
    setEmailCode(text)
  }

  const updateEmailForCode = () => {
    updateUserAttributes({
      userAttributes: {
        email: email
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      setViewEmail(false)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  const confirmUpdateEmail = () => {
    confirmSignUp({
      username: user.username,
      confirmationCode: emailCode
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      setEditProfile(!editProfile)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error confirming sign up', error);
    });
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {
        viewEmail
          ? <View style={styles.content}>
              <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Update Email</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setEditProfile(!editProfile)}} >
                  <X height={26} width={26} color={'#e94f4e'}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <InputFieldComponent 
                palceholder='First Name'
                label='User'
                value={email}
                handleFunction={updateEmail}
                secure={false}
                validation={true}
              />
              <MainButton label={'Update Email'} handleFunction={() => {updateEmailForCode()}}/>
            </View>
          : <View style={styles.content}>
              <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Confirm Code</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setEditProfile(!editProfile)}} >
                  <X height={26} width={26} color={'#e94f4e'}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <InputFieldComponent 
                palceholder='Confirmation Code'
                label='User'
                value={emailCode}
                handleFunction={updateCode}
                secure={false}
                validation={true}
              />
              <MainButton label={'Confirm Code'} handleFunction={() => {confirmUpdateEmail()}}/>
            </View>
      }
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0'
  },
  content: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingVertical: 25,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 32
  },
  header: {
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  pictureText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 16
  },
  placeHolder: {
    height: 125,
    width: 125,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 16,
    marginTop: 8
  },
  image: {
    height: 125,
    width: 125,
    borderRadius: 16,
    marginTop: 8
  },
  imageIcon: {
    height: 18,
    width: 18,
    color: '#e93f3e',
    margin: 10,
    marginLeft: 14
  },
  menuOptions: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
})

export default EditEmailProfileComponent
```